# How to add 3 buttons in each rows

Tags: java, android

I want to add 3 buttons in each row where as ROW created by dynamic way. I tried below way but it shows one button each row.

```
 LinearLayout ll_rootOBJ = findViewById(R.id.ll_root);
        LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        int total_items=13;
        for (int k=0; k<total_items; k++)
        {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.setTag(k);

            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setTag(k);
            b.setText("Button " + k);
            ll.addView(b);
            mainLayout.addView(ll);
        }

        ll_rootOBJ.addView(mainLayout);
```

Any help will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: You're only creating one button in each loop, not 3... You need a nested loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy answer would be to just add 3 buttons in each iteration. I case it's the last iteration and there are less buttons to add just add less:

```
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    int totalItems = 13;
    for (int k=0; k<totalItems; k+=3)
    {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setTag(k/3);

        int numberOfButtonsInRow = (k + 3 < totalItems) ? 3 : totalItems % 3;

        for(int l = 0; l < numberOfButtonsInRow; l++)
        {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setTag(k + l);
            b.setText("Button " + (k + l));
            layout.addView(b);
        }

        mainLayout.addView(layout);
    }
```

Also I would suggest to extract the contents of the inner loop to a separate function, although I left it here to make it brief.

Comment: where is mainlayout ?

Comment: I ommited the 3 first lines from the original code in my answer. You can copy them from above, it's the same, although I should probably remove the last line from my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your answer so that it makes me clear too.. Thanks

Comment: Updated - does it make sense?

Comment: Oh Okay, Yeah, Executed, Looks fine, I misunderstood his question though.. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Just add two more buttons to your "LinearLayout ll" view in another *for* loop

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
    LinearLayout ll_rootOBJ = findViewById(R.id.ll_root);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int k=0; k<13; k++)
    {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.setTag(k);

        for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setTag(k);
            b.setText("Button");
            ll.addView(b);
        }
        mainLayout.addView(ll);

    }

    ll_rootOBJ.addView(mainLayout);
```

This will give exactly what you want. Happy Coding..

[image]

Is this how you want? (in the picture)

Comment: No sir, It shows Button 0-0-0 and next row button 1-1-1.

Comment: Edited my answer, Please check.. @KankanaMayani

Comment: No sir, same issue.